# SSIS Expression Builder - GetDate() To String (dd-MMM-yy)

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, expression, etl

I am trying to convert GETDATE() to a string in SSIS in the format of dd-MMM-yy (ex;, 03-NOV-17) as I am using Oracle as a data source.

I've developed the expression below, which will return 2017-11-03. This is close, but I need the "11" to read "NOV".

```
(DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yy" , GETDATE())  + "-" + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()), 2)  + 
"-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd" , GETDATE()), 2)
```

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1):

The SSIS expression builder doesn't support the `DATENAME` function, for example.

I would return this from an Execute SQL Task (mapping the result to a string variable), e.g.:

```
SELECT UPPER(FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd-MMM-yy')) Result
```

You could also set it in a Script Task, e.g.:

```
Dts.Variables["User::StringDate"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yy").ToUpper();
```

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the info.  I'm sort of new to SSIS here.  I was able to set up the Execute SQL Task and map the result to my string value, but then how to I get that to work in the variable?

Comment: Running that task will set the variable for you, and then you can use it throughout the package, so just make sure that task runs before the ones you need the date for. So when you're designing you can just leave the variable blank (or insert a placeholder (e.g., set the value to "Placeholder") if you need to - sometimes you can't put variables into other tasks or expressions if they're blank - you'll know if you need a placeholder as you'll get an error along those lines at design time).

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

In SSIS expression the is no functions that can be used to change a date format

## Solution

You can use the `? :` conditional to achieve this. *[Microsoft Docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression)*

The following expression can be use to convert the date value returned by `GETDATE()` function to `dd-MMM-yy` format:

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd" , GETDATE()), 2)  + "-" +
(DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()) == 1 ? "JAN" :
DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()) ==  2 ? "FEB"  : 
DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()) == 3 ? "MAR"  :
DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()) == 4 ? "APR"   :
DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()) == 5 ? "MAY" : 
DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()) == 6 ? "JUN"  :
DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()) == 7 ? "JUL"  :
DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()) == 8 ? "AUG"  :
DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()) == 9 ? "SEP"  : 
DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()) == 10 ? "OCT"  : 
DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()) == 11 ? "NOV"  : 
DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()) == 12 ? "DEC" :"") 
+ "-" +  RIGHT( (DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yy" , GETDATE()),2)
```

## Other Solution

You can achieve this by adding a script task and writing a c# or Vb.net code to do this formatting

```
Dim FormatedDate as Date = Date.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yy")
```